# Can "GROUP BY" be used in a relationship query

Tags: soql

Can any one let me know if "GROUP BY" can be used in a relationship query.

In the given Query, I'm using "GROUP BY" to identify the same product name in a relationship.

```
SELECT gmod__product__r.name, Sum(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c, Sum(gmod__Quantity__c) gmod__Qunatity__c, COUNT(id) Quantity
FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c GROUP BY gmod__product__r.name
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: What issue did you face with the query? Are you getting any compilation error or not getting the data you need?

Comment: @ singularity:When i use the  Query it works fine in the Developer console.But when i use in the controller it does not displays the data.

Answer (score 4):

Group by can be used with relationship queries. For ex., following query works and returns the appropriate data.

```
select account.name, count(id) from contact group by account.name limit 100
```